# Populating a Hashmap with a vector of string slices in rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I've been pulling my hair out with this one.
I apologize in advance if it's a poorly worded question.

So, I have a Hashmap in the outer scope and want to populate it with string slices.

```
// Hashmap declaration.
let mut words: std::collections::HashMap< &str, std::vec::Vec<&str> > = std::collections::HashMap::new();

for file_name in ["conjuctions", "nouns", "verbs"].iter() { // Reading some file.
                
    let file_content = std::fs::read_to_string("../wordlists/{file_name}.txt");
        
    let mut fc = match file_content {
        Ok(file_content) => file_content,
        Err(_) => panic!("Failed to read the file: ../wordlists/{file_name}.txt"),
    };

    let mut wordlist_vec: Vec<&str> = fc.split("\n").collect();
    words.insert( file_name, wordlist_vec );
}

println!(words["conjunctions"])
// Using it outside the above scope throws an error. That FC was dropped but still borrowed.
```

So basically, my question is, how can I use the hash map outside the scope for the loop above?
I think the issues emanate from using string slices (split returns slices ig) but I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to use an owned `String` instead of `&str`s.

```rust
let mut words: HashMap<String, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();

// ...
   
   // We use map to change the elements of the iterator to owned Strings.             
   let mut wordlist_vec: Vec<String> = fc.split("\n").map(String::from).collect();
            
   words.insert(file_name.to_string(), wordlist_vec);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you please explain why? Like why can I not deep copy string slices?

Comment: @UbdusSamad `String::from` is a deep copy on a `&str`. It copies the data pointed at by the `&str`.

Comment: I see, so calling `clone` on the vector itself does not deep copy the string slices, right?

Comment: It would if you had slices in there (`str`), but you only have references to slices (`&str`). And copying a reference just crates another reference.